# Overload error when splitting string in Anypoint Studio to create new filename

Tags: mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I am using Mule 4 and Anypoint Studio 7.

I am looking at renaming the file that I'm processing with the timestamp that it has been processed.  So **test.csv** becomes **test+2019-01-30T16:32:56.95Z.csv**.

My issue is that it appears to work when I run the application but there is an error showing against the "Set Variable" component where I set the create filename to use by using the expression below:

```
#["myfolder/" ++ (payload.key splitBy("."))[0] ++ "+" ++ now() ++ "." ++ (payload.key splitBy("."))[1]]
```

The error message that I see on the "Set Variable" component is:

```
Unable to call any overload of function `splitBy` with arguments (String | Null, String) overloads:
    - splitBy(text: String, separator: String) -> Array<String> reason:     
        - Expecting Type: String, but got: Null.
        TIP: Try using `default` operator to avoid nullable objects.
        TIP: Use `!` value selector modifier to assert that an optional field is always present.
    - splitBy(text: String, regex: Regex) -> Array<String> reason:  
        - Expecting Type: String, but got: Null.
        TIP: Try using `default` operator to avoid nullable objects.
        TIP: Use `!` value selector modifier to assert that an optional field is always present.
        - Expecting Type: Regex, but got: String.
```

How can I resolve this error?  I have tried the tips to use default but the error still shows.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that  for some reason the metadata of your payload says that your key is `optional or nullable`. So data weaves type checker fails by saying that your script is going to fail what that happens. So in order to fix this you can simple do

```
#["myfolder/" ++ (payload.key default "." splitBy("."))[0] ++ "+" ++ now() ++ "." ++ (payload.key default "." splitBy("."))[1]]
```

The `default` operator will make sure that your value is not nullable